# rsync through ssh cannot find uppercase remote host (an other container in Docker)

Tags: docker, ssh, rsync

I'm running docker containers on a host, all of them in one bridge network. I'm using rsync among others to transfer data between them. I have CamelCase container names. I have no problem connecting to other running containers with these names from a Java application through REST for example, but rsync/ssh cannot handle them.

```
root@container-id:/# rsync -av /sourceFolder user@CamelCaseContainer:/targetFolder

ssh: Could not resolve hostname camelcasecontainer: Name or service not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
```

So for whatever reason, it changes the hostname to lowercase, and of course this way it cannot find the remote machine. If I want to connect to a container that has no uppercase letters in its name, everything is fine. (My images have a Debian base layer and the docker host is Ubuntu.)

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSH is trying to resolve the hostname to IP address using DNS and it is [not case sensitive](https://serverfault.com/questions/261341/is-the-hostname-case-sensitive).

It depends on what service is resolving your DNS names, but most likely there will be some bug. OpenSSH does it the expected way.